# series using program

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement my own sin(x) function via maclaurin series using C program, 
this is what I have so far, I worked everything on paper first then I tried to implement it it in a code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383
int main()
{
int x,nOfterms,term=1,i,j;
double numerator,sum=0.0,radius;
long int denominator;
printf("\n\t\tINPUT:");
printf("\n\t\t------");
printf("\n\t\tEnter the value for x in degrees:  ");
scanf("%d",&x);
printf("\n\t\tEnter the value for number of terms:  ");
scanf("%d",&nOfterms);
printf("\n\t\tOUTPUT:");
printf("\n\t\t-------");
radius=x*(PI/180.0);
printf("\n\t\tThe radius value for the given x value is:  %lf",radius);
for(i=1;i<=nOfterms;i+=2)
 {
     numerator=1.0;
     denominator=1;
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
     {
        numerator=numerator*radius;
        denominator=denominator*j;
     }
    sum=(sum+numerator)/(denominator*term);
    term=term*-1;
 }
printf("\n\t\tThe value for sin %d is:  %lf",x,sum);
printf("\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

I can't use the math.h at all in my code or so does the professor say, 
My output is all zeros which is not right obviously, also I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this, also if anyone can offer a way where I can see each iteration for each number of term of the series on the screen before I arrive at the answer, tried to place the last printf in the for loop but I'll end up with weird symbols and numbers.

Comment: If the problem is with the math, this isn't the proper site (although someone may still be able to help).  If the problem is with the code, you'll get a better response if you post what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in in the implementation of the Mac Laurin series. The line

```
sum=(sum+numerator)/(denominator*term);
```

is wrong. It should be simply :

```
sum += numerator/denominator*term;
```

Remaining is fine. I tried it and found sin(30) = 0.5, sin(60) = 0.866 and even sin(90) ~ 1.

But you algorythm is not very efficient since for each term you start back from 1/1 when the first elements of i<sup>n</sup> / i! have already been computed on previous term.

You could change your loops to :

```
numerator=1.0;
denominator=1;
j = 1;
for(i=1;i<=nOfterms;i+=1)
 {
        numerator=numerator*radius;
        denominator=denominator*j++;
        sum += numerator/denominator*term;
        term=term*-1;
        numerator=numerator*radius;
        denominator=denominator*j++;
 }
```

Tested and give same (correct) results.

Comment: thank you serge, I now understand what I was doing wrong, it's so frustrating that I can do it on paper but I can't figure how to implement it in code, would there be any c book that deal with how to implement math algorithms that you can recommend

Comment: @HummingDev : Not really. I can just give you the old advice : keep away from the keyboard until you have written the algorythm in pseudo-code with paper and pencil, and only then translate it in true C (or whatever language).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems with your code to help you along:

- You want to increment `i` by 1, not 2 as you count the number of terms.
- For each term, you want only the odd powers of `x`, so it's `j` you need to increment by 2 (change the upper limit and denominator factorial calculation appropriately)
- This line is wrong: `sum=(sum+numerator)/(denominator*term);` and should presumably be `sum=sum+numerator/(denominator*term);`

Hope that helps with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `for` loop is not correct. Manually trace through it for a few values of `i`:

```
 1: numerator=radius, denominator=1 (correct)
 2: numerator=radius, denominator=1 (incorrect)
 3: numerator=radius*radius, denominator=3 (incorrect)
```

Correct inner loop should be:

```
 for (j = 1; j < i*2; ++j) 
 {
    numerator = numerator * radius;
    denominator = denominator * j;
 }
```